# PHP Глобальный объект

Tags: php, global-variables

Есть ли такая штука в PHP? А то я пробую статические поля, $_SERVER, $GLOBAL, все приводит к одному и тому же результату, при перезагрузке страницы всё это исчезает.

То есть такой код (или аналогичный с другими способами):

```
$_SERVER['test'] = 'test';
```

При попытке на другой странице вывести вот так:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['test']);
```

Дает NULL. Я где то что-то не так делаю или в PHP нет совсем глобальных объектов?

П.с. Не нужно рассказывать, что глобальные объекты это плохо, что при падении сервера все данные слетят. Мне нужно просто сдать лабу в универе и забыть php навсегда, поэтому не хочу заморачиваться с сериализацией объекта и сохранением ) )

Comment: "Что глобальный объекты это плохо" - никто вам это и не говорил. В PHP такое понятие просто отсутствует. Используйте какое-то хранилище. Memcache или что-то подобное.

Comment: на уровне приложения - любые варианты для кэширования, на уровне клиента - сессии. Если у вас лаба в универе то это сессии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первой строке пишем `session_start()`
Далее даже при перезагрузке страницы массив $_SESSION не будет сбрасываться.
Содержимое массива будет доступно только тому пользователю, который запустил скрипт (открыл страницу).
Для доступа к общим данным несколькими пользователями нужно использовать базу данных или кэш. Зависит от задачи.

```
$array = [1,2,34,4,5];
file_put_contents('file.txt', serialize($array));

Получение данных:
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

Comment: О, кажется это то, что нужно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Добиться этого можно работая с сессиями, например. `$_SESSION[someVar] = 'haxfax';`, правда перед этим сессию необходимо инициализировать.

Подробнее тут: [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php)

---

Либо пишем в файл, либо в ДБ

С файлом по моему, наиболее костыльно-простецкий способ.

Comment: Увы это полностью противоречит главной цели, из-за которой я решил прибегнуть к такому злу как глобальный объект - избежать сериализации и сохранения в БД

Comment: @Uraty ну тогда сессии/файл.
По сути, это достаточно похожие вещи, учитывая, что сессии пхп пишет в файлы, только там функционала поболе.